# Cи - очень странная проблема с fscanf

Tags: c

Есть следующий код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BICYCLE 1
#define MOTORCYCLE 2
#define CAR 4
#define TRUCK 8

typedef struct {
    int orderNumber, type, passengers, cost;
} TRANSPORT;

void printAllTransports(TRANSPORT*);
int countOfTransportByType(TRANSPORT*, const int);
int getIncome(TRANSPORT*);
void shellSort(TRANSPORT* transports);
void swap(TRANSPORT*, TRANSPORT*);

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
char path[100]; 
int orderNumber, type, passengers, count = 0, i;
FILE* inputFile; TRANSPORT* transports;

if (argc < 2) {
    printf("Enter, please, file path.\n");
    scanf_s("%s", path);

    if ((inputFile = fopen(path, "r+")) == NULL) {
        printf("ERROR: file isn't opened.\n");
        _getch();
        return -1;
    }

    free(path);
} else {
    if ((inputFile = fopen(argv[1], "r+")) == NULL) {
        printf("ERROR: file isn't opened.\n");
        _getch();
        return -1;
    }
}

while ((i = fscanf(inputFile, "%d%d%d", &orderNumber, &type, &passengers)) != EOF) {
    if (type != BICYCLE && type != MOTORCYCLE && type != CAR && type != TRUCK) {
        printf("INPUT DATA ERROR: wrong type of transport.\n");
        _getch();
        return -1;
    }

    printf("while: order: %d, type: %d, passengers: %d\n", orderNumber, type, passengers);
    count++;
}

rewind(inputFile);

transports = (TRANSPORT*) malloc(sizeof(int)*4*count);

for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    fscanf(inputFile, "%d%d%d%d\n", &orderNumber, &type, &passengers);
    transports[i].orderNumber = orderNumber;
    transports[i].passengers = passengers;
    transports[i].type = type;
    printf("for: order: %d, type: %d, passengers: %d\n", orderNumber, type, passengers);

    switch (type) {
    case BICYCLE: transports[i].cost = 1; break;
    case MOTORCYCLE: transports[i].cost = 2; break;
    case CAR: transports[i].cost = 5; break;
    case TRUCK: transports[i].cost = 10; break;
    }
}

printAllTransports(transports);

printf("Shell sorting transports by passengers...\n\n");
shellSort(transports);
printAllTransports(transports);

printf("Number of bicycles: %d\n", countOfTransportByType(transports, BICYCLE));
printf("Number of motorcycles: %d\n", countOfTransportByType(transports, MOTORCYCLE));
printf("Number of cars: %d\n", countOfTransportByType(transports, CAR));
printf("Number of trucks: %d\n", countOfTransportByType(transports, TRUCK));

printf("\n\n");

printf("Money incoming: %d\n", getIncome(transports));
_getch();
return 0;
}
```

И вот внутри while творится какая-то неясная мне магия, из-за которой программа не хочет функционировать. Есть следующий файл:

```
 1 1 2
 2 1 2
 3 1 2
 4 2 4
 5 2 2
 6 4 4
 7 4 6
 8 8 10
 9 8 16
```

Программа успешно считывает все данные. Через printf все данные успешно выводятся в консоль, НО после того, как данные выводятся, fscanf выдает ошибку:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x0f88e42e (msvcr100d.dll) in Usachev.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.
```

И указывает на input.c файл, на следующие две строчки:

```
if (longone)
*(long UNALIGNED *)pointer = (unsigned long)number;
```

И еще немного информации:

- Я пробовал использовать вместо проверки != EOF просто == 3, однако данная ошибка все равно есть.
- Если убрать проверку на что-либо вообще и оставить просто fscanf в while, то ошибки не будет, но цикл станет бесконечным.

Может кто-нибудь объяснить как решить данную проблему и сделать так, чтобы данные успешно считывались?

Comment: И? Ошибка вылетает в коде, который не имеет никакого отношения к вашему `fscanf`. Очевидно указатель `pointer` имеет нулевое значение. Зачем вы привели здесь этот посторонний огрызок кода с `fscanf`? И почему не приведен код, который действительно относится к данной проблеме?

Comment: Прямое отношение, ведь через него я считываю данные. Я не могу решить проблему, чтобы считать данные и не поймать ошибку. Предложите другое решение, если не можете ответить, почему fscanf приводит к ошибке.

Comment: Где остальной код? Где хотя бы объявления переменных? В каком месте *вашего* кода происходит вылет?

Comment: Сделал дополнение кода. Вылет происходит внутри while, где fscanf. При чем он считывает все данные из файла, а потом, когда, по идее, должен был вернуть EOF, просто ломает программу ошибкой, указанной вверху.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что это

```
fscanf(inputFile, "%d%d%d%d\n", &orderNumber, &type, &passengers);
```

?

Четыре `%d`, но только три аргумента. Неудивительно, что `fscanf` будет непредсказуемо падать.

Также указывать `\n` в формате `fscanf` смысла нет. Спецификатор `%d` и так сам по себе пропускает пробельные символы.

Comment: Точно, спасибо большое. Немного невнимательный после нескольких часов :)